# Keyboard symbols popping up when using a blue tooth keyboard

Tags: settings

I just wondered how to turn these off.  They are really annoying and come up all the time when I am using my blue tooth mouse.  I can't type the next word until I pick a vowel with a symbol which is absolutely incorrect.  How can I turn this blue tooth keyboard feature off completely?

Comment: What phone are you using? And what keyboard app is selected (i.e. it comes up when the Bluetooth keyboard is not connected)?

Comment: Thanks for responding so fast. It is a Galaxy tab 10.1 with a blue tooth keyboard.

Comment: Are you selecting the keyboard buttons with the onscreen mouse pointer? Or are you using your fingers, and the symbols are showing up when you type only because you have a bluetooth mouse connected (and the keyboard works normally when it isn't connected)?

Comment: Also, I see the title of the question mentions a bluetooth keyboard. Could you clarify a bit more about your setup?